# Jersey Viewable displaying json instead of JSP

Tags: java, rest, jsp, jersey

I am newbie to jersey and have a small application developed which uses Viewable. But in the browser, it is displaying the JSON rather than the content of the JSP.

Here is my web.xml

```
            <display-name>Demo</display-name>
        <filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.demo</param-value>
    </init-param>
            <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.jsp.JspMvcFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.mvc.templateBasePath.jsp</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Jersey</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My ResourceConfig class:

```
    @ApplicationPath("/rest")
    public class RestApplication extends ResourceConfig 
    {
     public RestApplication() {
     packages("com.demo");
             //register(JspMvcFeature.class);
     property(JspMvcFeature.TEMPLATE_BASE_PATH, "/WEB-INF/views/");
     }
    }
```

My Resource class:

```
     @Path("/token")
     public class TokenResource {
            @GET
        @Path("/getAccessToken")
        public Viewable getAccessToken(){
                   Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<>();
                   return new Viewable("/home.jsp", model);
            }
          }
```

This is the output in my browser:

```
         {"templateName":"/home.jsp","templateNameAbsolute":true}
```

I have referred to the other posts available online. And some of the examples posted seem to be working for them. I would like to know if there is something that I am missing. Thanks much in advance.